# This inner product is positive?

Tags: linear-algebra

It seems easy but I couldn't prove:
[image]
Where $A$ is a linear operator

Maybe I'm forgetting something, I need help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is $A$ symmetric?

Comment: @user7530 no, it's not symmetric

Answer (score 2):

As Michael points out, the statement is false. $A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & -1\\1 & 0\end{array}\right]$ is an explicit counterexample: $\langle Ax, x\rangle = 0$ for all $x$ but $\langle A^2x, x\rangle < 0$ for nonzero $x$.

Notice that if $A$ is symmetric, it has full real eigenvectors with nonnegative eigenvalues and you can easily prove the statement by decomposing $x$ in the eigenbasis. If $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ are the eigenvectors, and $x = \sum \alpha_i v_i$, then

$$\langle A^2x, x\rangle = \langle \sum \lambda_i^2\alpha_iv_i, \sum \alpha_i v_i\rangle = \sum \alpha_i^2 \lambda_i^2 \geq 0.$$

Comment: If A is a positive operator, it's true it's symmetric?

Comment: Yes. Or Hermitian.

Comment: I didn't understand how "decomposing $x$ in the eigenbasis" could answer the question.

Comment: I've added more details.

Comment: you made a typo, in the end is $\ge$. Thank you